# Rxjs combining bufferCount and bufferTime

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

Using Rxjs, I'm looking for a way to create an observable that

- buffers `N` events
- OR buffer what it can under an `interval`.

After a certain time interval, it emits what has been accumulated till then.

I looked into `bufferCount` and `bufferTime`. However, I am unable to understand how to combine both behaviors such that it guarantees at least one to be fulfilled. so that all events are processed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`bufferTime`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/bufferTime) operator allows you to specify an optional max buffer size. So you can do something like this:

```js
bufferTime(2000, null, 5) // <-- buffer emits @ 2000ms OR when 5 items collected
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot 